# why "dir" global attribute's value does not effect on "left" and "right" CSS attributes?

Tags: localization

according to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) : "If both left and right are specified, left wins when direction is ltr (English, horizontal Japanese, etc.) and right wins when direction is rtl"

I tried placing both attributes as the example above but it didn't work and the last CSS attribute ("right") took over instead of dynamically set "left" attribute to take over.

I placed "dir" attribute with value "ltr" at the body tag.
I placed "left" attritube and then "right" CSS attributes at the same time with values: "50%".
I expected that "left" CSS attribute will take over when dir="left" and "right" CSS attribute will take-over when dir="rtl".
Actual results were: The browser made the last attribute value assignment "right":"50%" eventhough dir="ltr".

Here's the Template:

```
<body dir="ltr">
...
<section class="about" id="about">
     <div class="max-width">
        <h2 class="title">About me</h2>
     </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section .title::after {
position: absolute;
bottom: -12px;
/* left : 50%; Should work only if dir="ltr" */
left: 50%;
/* right: 50%; Should work only if dir="rtl" but Actual result is right: 50% any case*/
right: 50%;
padding: 5px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The definition from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is correct. The problem is you CSS code, it's because you are setting style for ::after pseudo element instead of h2 with class .title

Change to this:

```css
section .title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  /* left : 50%; Should work only if dir="ltr" */
  left: 50%;
  /* right: 50%; Should work only if dir="rtl" but Actual result is right: 50% any case*/
  right: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

and it will work as you expect.
**Note**: In CSS, ::after creates a pseudo-element that is the last child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default. Refer to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).